# Having trouble loading php curl results

Tags: php, curl

So I'm having a problem with the following code.

I've got `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` set to `true`, yet nothing is returned when `curl_exec` is hit. Any and all help is appreciated!

```
<?php

    $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";  
    $yql_query = "select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO,GOOG,AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv' and columns='symbol,price,date,time,change,col1,high,low,col2'"; 
    $yql_params = "&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";

    $yql_url = $yql_base_url . urlencode($yql_query) . $yql_params;  

    $session = curl_init($yql_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $json = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    $phpObj = json_decode($json);

    if(!is_null($phpObj->query->results))
    {  
        echo $phpObj->query->results;
    }  

?>
```

Comment: It looks to me like your query is returning good data, but I wouldn't expected an echo to work on the results object.  Try print_r() or var_dump(). ie: print_r($phpObj->query->results);

Answer (score 0):

`$phpObj->query->results` is an array of Object and you can not do `echo` on it. Simply use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on it.

Example:

```
print_r($phpObj->query->results);
var_dump($phpObj->query->results);
```